# Temporarily disable quantity discounts in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, discounts

Currently i am using default OpenCart discounts dependent on quantity. 
For example
1 item - 10 $ each
5 items and more - 9 $ each

For a short period of time, i want to disable this option, and make prices same for all quantities.
In this case:
1 item or more - 10 $ each.

The problem is, that after this period, i have to switch back to old discounts dependent on quantity. Is it possible to implement this functionality without going through all items and editing discounts manualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is! You can use the `oc_product_discount` table's `date_start` field to do that. Let's say you'd like to disable these until 1st January 2015. Run the following query to do that (I'm assuming you haven't changed the DB_PREFIX in your config.php file, so it's `oc_`):

```
UPDATE oc_product_discount
SET date_start = '2015-01-01'
```

Please note: you have to provide the date in a YYYY-MM-DD format.

Using this solution would save you from the headache of possibly forgetting to change it back, as it would not be necessary. It just tells Opencart, that these discounted prices should take place from the date you've specified. I hope this was thing you were looking for.